# Python - What is the most efficient way to generate padding?

Tags: python, padding

Here's the problem: I'm reading binary files in fairly large blocks (512 KiB) and wish to pad the last block with zeros whenever it is shorter than the block size.

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
bytes = f.read(self.chunksize)
if len(bytes) > 0:
    len_diff = self.chunksize - len(bytes)
    if len_diff > 0:
        bytes += reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, ["\0" for i in range(0, len_diff)])
```

Obviously this is terribly inefficient since that reduce will make a lot of string concatenations. I'm wondering though, how can I achieve this with Python? In C, I'd simply calloc and be done with it.

If it isn't achievable with Python, I'm willing to convert this code into a C module and/or abandon Python entirely for this project, since it's still on the early stages.

Cheers!

**EDIT**: I'm feeling terrible for not remembering to use the * operator. :-)

This solution worked perfectly for me:

```
bytes += "\0" * len_diff
```

**EDIT #2**: Using ljust() instead simplified my code a bit, so the correct answer goes to Jeff.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you're working with strings, you can use [`ljust()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to do the padding.

```
readBytes = f.read(self.chunksize)
if readBytes:
    readBytes = readBytes.ljust(self.chunksize, b'\0')
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for. I don't do much string manipulation these days. :P

Comment: In Python 3, the second parameter to ljust must be `b'\0'`.

Answer (score 6):

```
bytes += "\0"*len_diff
```

should help

Comment: I even feel bad for not thinking about this first. :) Will accept as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Sorry, the solution given for @Jeff is actually what I was looking for, much less hackish. This one works too, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
bytes = "\0" * self.chunksize
rbytes = f.read(self.chunksize)
bytes[:len(rbytes)] = rbytes
```

or

```
bytes = f.read(self.chunksize)
bytes += "\0" * (self.chunksize - len(bytes))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
bytes += "\0"*len_diff
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pad something encrypted. Here's how to do it.

```py
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

...
_bytes = pad(_bytes, block_size)
```